# Installing matplotlib on RedHat ideally using yum

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, installation, yum

I can't seem to find documentation on this. Matplotlib says to run:

```
sudo yum install python-matplotlib
```

which installs all the dependancies and this version of matplotlib successfully:

```
python-matplotlib.x86_64 0:0.99.1.2-1.6.amzn1
```

However, I use python2.7, separately installed. The original (and still existing) python2.6 now imports matplotlib successfully. Is there a related matplotlib package on RedHat for python2.7? I don't know [how to use this page on python-matplotlib packages](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python-matplotlib).

Other info:

- `which python2.6` returns `/usr/bin/python2.6`
- `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`.
- `cat /proc/version` returns
  `Linux version 3.14.23-22.44.amzn1.x86_64 ... (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC) ...`

Something else I tried:
I also tried to use pip2.7 instead, [installed all the dependancies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9843560/2553191), and it [broke on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663620/2553191) concerning permissions. The solution is to reset the permissions of the problem file with:

```
chmod o+x /path/to/file
```

However, it's a temporary copied file. :( During the install of matplotlib it recopies this file over, so I can't set permissions on it. Here is the place it is broken:

```
g++ ... -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/matplotlib/backends/_backend_agg.so
running install_lib
copying pylab.py -> /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py'
```

This doesn't seem like the right way to do it, it's too cobbled together.

Question asked first at the [Unix&Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189604/86075).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built from source. :( Surprisingly not that difficult, but ran into a lot of problems doing the interactive part (Redhat 4 is too old to have packages for most things that let you do interactive backends, I need a newer machine).

```
# get matplotlib
wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.3/matplotlib-1.4.3.tar.gz

#uncompress
tar xvzf matplotlib-1.4.3.tar.gz

# open build install
# read INSTALL file for more instructions
cd matplotlib-1.4.3
python setup.py build
# actually installing needed superuser privileges
sudo python setup.py install
```

Hope this saves time for anyone else with a similar setup.

Answer (score 0):

On centos 7 I installed `python 3.6.1`, into `/usr/local`

This also automatically installed `pip`

Then I ran `sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3.6 install matplotlib`

and it was all good

Comment: How did you install Python 3.6.1 into /usr/local?

Comment: install from source, I believe that the default target is /usr/local, if not use the --prefix option in configure